# SQL Server Concatenation & Display in VB

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

(Trying to build a bank functionality website)

I'm trying to concatenate fields that are int and varchar in a stored procedure and SQL Server is showing the error: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Checking' to data type int.

The concatenation from SQL then needs to be shown in a drop down list.

Any help on concatenating? Also the bank numbers must be shown in a dropdownlist in VB as XXXXXX0123 any suggestions for this encryption or display - either stored in SQL or the DDL.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To concatenate  int and varchar , First you should convert int to varchar

```
 convert(varchar,anyint)+' '+'varchar string';
```

it will remove your : Conversion failed  ERROR

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, you cannot concatenate anything other than strings. So you must at least use the `CONVERT()` pseudo-function. Here's an example:

```
DECLARE @myInt INT = 42
DECLARE @myVarChar VARCHAR(MAX) = 'My number is ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), @myInt)
```

In your case, it appears that you want to format the number with leading zeroes. There are several ways to do this, but the way I tend to do it looks like the following:

```
SET @myVarChar = 'Formatted = ' + RIGHT('0000000000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), @myInt), 10)
```

This prefixes the converted number with 10 zeroes, and then takes the 10 rightmost set of digits, which will include all of the digits from your original number and however many padding zeroes are needed to bring the total length to 10.